# MatLab: Create an 3D array out of x,y,z coordinates and corresponding intensity values

Tags: arrays, image, matlab, 3d, 2d

I have a large 2D-array (31100 x 4) built up like this:

Intensity |  X  | Y  |  Z

out of this array I would like to create a 3D-array to visualize it as a 3D-image.

I would somehow have to transform the 2D into a 3D-array. Since there will be plenty of points where there is no intensity value available all of these points should be zero values.

Side information:

```
min(x) =  -152.0120;
max(x) =   161.4350;
min(y) =  -256.2560;
max (y) =   -52.3801;
min(z) =  -428.5920; 
max (z) =  -152.4210;
```

Because of the larger number of decimal places I might have to round up. Yet, this would possibly lead to several intensities being assigned to the same coordinate combination. Logically, I would have to add up the intensities in these cases.

This makes everything really complicated.

I would be happy if someone could teach me how to transform a 2D into a 3D array with zero-values for spots without intensity values.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: How are the points with no intensity value represented in the first place? You say that the data is in a 2D **array**. They should have a default value then. If it is blank (i e. ''), are you sure the data is stored in an array and not a cell?

Comment: Hello, what I meant is the following: there are positions (X,Y,Z) that are not defined by an intensity value. These positions are not even mentioned in the 2D-array. In this 2D-array are only positions listed that are defined by an intensity value.

Comment: Do the x,y,z positions form a lattice? Otherwise what you want is difficult to achieve

Comment: I believe you may be a bit confused. You have 4D data. you have 3D data of a geometry (XYZ) plus an intensity value for each of them. How would oyu like to plot this data? One option may be plot 3D points and change their colour with intensity or something like that. You need to be more specific, because you cannot make a 4D plot!

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Initially, I created a 3D-scatter for the spreadsheet I described above. However, I obtain a scatter-plot (of roughly human-organ shape.. that is what I do) but of course I cannot look in the inside. Hence, I might miss out something that is important. That is why I thought it might be a good idea to create a 3D array to be able to image the shape slice by slice with custom scripts like "imshow3". My initial problem is that I cannot slice the 3D-scatter.